# GAS : setFormula parenthesis or quotes missing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I want to put L2 = M2 , this works :

> for (var j = 2; j<=sheetold.getLastRow(); j++){
>
> sheetold.getRange(["L"]+[(j)]).setFormula('=["M"]+[(j)]');

But if I want the following L2 = (M2/P2), I am blocked (possibly some parenthesis or quotes misplaced on my part ??) :

> sheetold.getRange(["L"]+[(j)]).setFormula('=["M"]+[(j)]/["P"]+[(j)]');

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need so many square brackets "[]" or parentheses.

Try this:

```
for (var j = 2; j<=sheetold.getLastRow(); j++){
  sheetold.getRange("L"+j).setFormula('=(M'+j+'\/P'+j+')'); }
```