# GAS : setFormula and IF : correct syntax?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is the correct syntax for setFormula when there is an IF function included ?

I would like to adapt this formula in GAS :

```
=IF(AE2="","",((R2/Q2)-1))
```

I have tried this (thanks to [GAS : setFormula parenthesis or quotes missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290675/gas-setformula-parenthesis-or-quotes-missing)) :

```
for (var j = 2; j<=sheetold.getLastRow(); j++){

sheetold.getRange("AD"+j).setFormula('=IF'(AE'+j="","",((R'+j+'\/Q'+j+')-1))');
```

Alas I have a *"Missing ) after argument list"* error.

I am lost !

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Not sure about your use but the placing the following formula in AD2 should achieve the same. =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AE2="","",((R2/Q2)-1)))

Comment: Thanks Michael. But Harold below found the solution (see below). ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```
for (var j = 2; j<=sheetold.getLastRow(); j++){
  sheetold.getRange("AD"+j).setFormula('=IF(AE'+j+'="";"";((R'+j+'/Q'+j+')-1))');
}
```

the differences are:

IF'(AE --> IF(AE

and

, --> ;